# Removing feature from the view's popup feature array in ArcGIS Maps SDK JS?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, features, popup

Using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript version 4.x, it is possible for the view's popup to contain an [array of features](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#features). In this case, it is possible to page through them using the forward/back arrows.

Assume I wish to remove one of the features from the popup's `features` array programatically, so that it doesn't display in the popup. How can I do this cleanly?

In this [simple example](https://codepen.io/slead/pen/ZEmoBja), I manually remove the first feature from the array, and it is no longer possible to navigate forward/back in the popup. However, the forward/back buttons remain and the popup still lists "2 of 2" features.

[image]

(This is a simplistic example, and in reality I would use some logic to determine which of the features to delete.)

[clear](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#clear) removes all features, but I only wish to remove certain features programatically.

How can I remove the feature and also decrement the feature counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that ArcGIS Maps SDK JD does not detect change of `view.popup.features`
array if it's done by just overwriting original array with the JS `.splice` method. On possible solution is to create a new array and assign it to `view.popup.features`.

Code could then look something like this (tested):

```
reactiveUtils.watch(
  () => view.popup.features,
  () => {
    if (view.popup.features.length > 1){
      view.popup.features.splice(0, 1);
      view.popup.features = [].concat(view.popup.features);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: now I feel stoopid for not testing something so simple ;)